# Doing complex array queries in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to query a database and return only two results or one.

Here is my situation. I have a compound that needs to be split, then the array needs to be run through a database and it should only match 2 or 1 things in the database i.e.

I have NaHCO3 to split. The query should match only Na and HCO3. In the database i have: Na, H, C, O, CO3 & HCO3.

How do i do this?
Here is my lagging code.

```
<?php
  $compound ="NaHCO3";
  $arr1 = str_split($compound);

   SELECT name, formula
   FROM elements, ions
   WHERE name= $arr1['*']
   AND formula=$arr1['*']
   RETURN 2;
?>
```

Comment: Not actually. I just put that together a few mins ago. I can't think of a way to do this query. I am doing this another way and it is annoying the users. This method has to work somehow.

Comment: The other way i am doing this is using a table that specifies where elements and ions go depending on their charges. It works but it is too much work for the users. So i force the users to enter Na into td1 and HCO3 into td2 and then i take care of the rest. The users just want to enter NaHCO3 at once into one td.

Answer (score 2):

You can split compound and again implode it with `,` as glue and later use `IN` query 
May be some thing like this .. I am not sure..

```
<?
$compound ="NaHCO3";
  $arr1 = str_split($compound);
  foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v){
   $arr2[]="'".$v."'";
  }
  $str=implode(",",$arr2);
 $sql="SELECT name, formula
   FROM elements, ions
   WHERE name IN (".$str.")";
echo $sql;   
?>
```

output

```
SELECT name, formula FROM elements, ions WHERE name IN ('N','a','H','C','O','3')
```

Comment: I am dealing with lots of compounds of that sort. I thought about doing imploding but the ordering of elements is random and it renders it useless. Best chance is starting with comma separated arrays and using other validations like charges to narrow it down.